# IMAP SEARCH of Gmail not finding all messages

Tags: gmail

When I try to search Gmail via IMAP using `X-GM-THRID` it does not always find the related message. What could be the problem?

Comment: I don't think it is related to client. However, it is http://github.com/mscdex/node-imap